# Using SFINAE to check whether the class is same or is derived from another template class in C++98

Tags: c++, templates, stl, sfinae, c++98

I am trying to read STL collections and allocate memory in more efficient way for those collections that have `resize()` and `operator[]()` methods instead of using `std::insert_iterator`. I have also defined several non-STL collections that look like STL collection but they are not (some functions may not be implemented, for example `insert(iterator, const_reference)` and I can't use `std::insert_iterator` at all).

I have written the following function that reads the collection:

```
template<typename TSTLCollection> 
void ReadCollection(TSTLCollection* pCollection)
{
    ReadingCollectionFunctorClass<
            STLCollectionShouldBeResizedAndReadByIndex<TSTLCollection>::value
        >(pCollection);
}
```

I have a functor-template `ReadingCollectionFunctorClass<bool>` with two specializations for `true` and `false` values. They both implement a template member function

```
template<typename TSTLCollection>
void operator()(TSTLCollection*);
```

What I want next is to check which of these specializations must be called. To archive this I wrote this class:

```
template<typename TSTLCollection>
struct STLCollectionShouldBeResizedAndReadByIndex
{
private:
    template<typename TItem>
    static char f(NonSTLCollection<TItem>* pCollection, int);
    template<typename TItem>
    static char f(std::basic_string<TItem>* pCollection, int);
    template<typename TItem>
    static char f(std::vector<TItem>* pCollection, int);
    template<typename TCollection>
    static long f(TCollection* pCollection, ...);
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(f((TSTLCollection*)0, int())) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

If I call `ReadCollection(pStlCollection)` everything works great, but the problem is that it doesn't work if I call `ReadCollection(pClassDerivedFromStlCollection)`: `STLCollectionShouldBeResizedAndReadByIndex` doesn't have `value == true` for derived classes. What is wrong and how should I fix this?

**I can't use C++11 or C++14 features, only C++98. I can't use boost and other 3rd party libraries as well.**

Comment: Is that misplaced `)` in `enum { value = sizeof(f((TSTLCollection*)0), int()) == sizeof(char) };` a typo when you are posting here or a bug in your actual code? (And with that fixed, both clang and g++ report an ambiguity, as they should, when `STLCollectionShouldBeResizedAndReadByIndex` is instantiated with a derived class.)

Comment: A bug in the source code. I am investigating...

Comment: OK. When I've fixed misplaced `)` it actually raises a warning that ISO C++ doesn't allow this construction, but compiles with `value == true` as I need here. OK, the question still remains: how I should implement this in ISO C++ compilant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understood your intent clearly:

```
template <typename TSTLCollection>
struct STLCollectionShouldBeResizedAndReadByIndex
{
private:
    template <typename TItem>    
    static char f(NonSTLCollection<TItem>* pCollection);

    template <typename TItem>    
    static char f(std::basic_string<TItem>* pCollection);

    template <typename TItem>
    static char f(std::vector<TItem>* pCollection);

    static long f(...);

public:
    enum { value = sizeof(f((TSTLCollection*)0)) == sizeof(char) };
};
```

[<kbd>**LIVE DEMO**</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9fe78decc42ad87)

Comment: Hmm... Everything works. :) I it seemed to me that I'd checked this variant before writing the one from the post.